# Grails: Adding an attribute to model Map on every view, when model is not present

Tags: grails, filter

I've got a pretty clean filter which is intended to add an attribute to the model Map so that it can be shown on every page:

```
def filters = {
    someFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        after = { Map model ->
          model.something = 'hey!' // can't, since it's null
        }
    }
}
```

If model is null it fails horribly (`NullPointerException`, as expected). But if I add an `if (!model)` and try to instantiate it, it's local and doesn't behave as intended.

How can I put an empty map there when model is null?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with a little groovy triks. You can create a [groovy interceptor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3515-Interception) and apply it to all controllers class in bootstrap. The interceptor implements the afterInvoke method in which check for null results and turn them in empty maps [:]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. How would you generalize the Controllers so that you can intercept just that, and just the action methods?

Comment: Look her http://grails.org/doc/2.3.3/guide/plugins.html#evaluatingConventions . You can loop over controller classes. For action I think you can check method visibility with reflection. Theorically in a grails controller only actions need to be public, so you can intercept and apply only to public methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def filters = {
someFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
    after = { Map model ->
      model.put('something', 'hey!')
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this fails if model is null :(